# What are these four "debris" objects along with the Starlink satellites?

Tags: spacex, identify-this-object, debris, starlink

Celestrak has an updated system of categories for retrieving lists of current TLEs, and there's already one for Starlink, yay!

Currently https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/starlink.txt contains 64 objects from the 2019-029 SpaceX Starlink launch, from `OBJECT A, 44235U, 19029A` to `FALCON 9 DEB, 44298U, 19029BR`, which appears to be the 60 Starlink satellites plus 4 debris objects from the same launch.

**Question:** What are these four debris objects? Are any of them the 2nd stage?

[image: Celestrak's TLE groups] click for full size or go to [Celestrak elements](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/)

TLE eccentricity value versus estimated altitude from mean motion [as explained here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36471/12102). Four big blobs around 435 to 440 km are the four debris objects.

plotted using https://pastebin.com/cFLhTJVq

[image: "Starlink 60" plus debris June 1 and 29, 2019]

Comment: The Verge: [SpaceX is in communication with all but three of 60 Starlink satellites one month after launch](https://www.theverge.com/2019/6/28/19154142/spacex-starlink-60-satellites-communication-internet-constellation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They probably were part of the support and hold-down structure of the satellite stack.
You can see them in green on each side of the stack in this picture (Credit to [Origin_of_mind](https://www.reddit.com/user/Origin_of_Mind/) on reddit):

[image]

They were probably jettisoned shortly before the deployment of the satellites.  This also seems to be consistent with the optical characteristics (see [here](https://twitter.com/generuso/status/1133961769041444864))
A more detailed discussion can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/SpaceXLounge/comments/bu1n8b/how_starlink_satellites_were_stacked_under_the/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) .