# How do the Starlink satellites shine?

Tags: spacex, iss, artificial-satellite, communication, starlink

As we can see the Starlink satellites with the naked eye as they pass by. I was wondering about what makes them visible.

Do they have large mirrors that reflect the sunlight making them look as if they have lights on board or do they actually have lights.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Starlink (and other satellites) categorically do not have exterior lights or illumination, that would be a waste of power for no particular benefit.

The reason that we can sometimes see satellites or other spacecraft at night is because the spacecraft is still exposed to daylight. Here is an image describing this phenomena:

[image: Diagram of spotting satellites]
<sup>(image credit: Gary Meader; from the book "Night Sky With The Naked Eye" by Bob King)</sup>

Satellites and other orbiting bodies (ie the Moon) appear so bright because they're reflecting sunlight. Even though they aren't covered in mirrors, the sun is just so bright that white paint or the lunar surface is enough to let us see even tiny satellites from hundreds of kilometers away.

Occasionally, a [satellite will "Flare"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_flare) which is when the angle of the sun on its glass solar panels reflects directly to the observer. This reflection off the solar panels rather than simply the body of the satellite can appear much brighter temporarily.

Comment: some satellites shoot lasers for LIDAR and other studies (that we can't see), and there's [this](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/f/fitsat-1) but it's pretty rare but I don't know if it's one-of-a-kind, so I've asked [Besides FITSat-1 (Fukuoka Institute of Technology CubeSat) have any satellites had lights meant to be visible on Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40534/12102)

Comment: @OrganicMarble possibly from [here](https://www.universetoday.com/131270/celebrate-power-naked-eye-observing-new-book/), but it should be credited in the question.

Comment: I love how the bird actually looks avian!

Comment: The credit is mandatory, not optional. You can't just steal other people's work. Beyond that, do we even have rights to republish it here in the first place?

Comment: As an aside, that book looks interesting!

Comment: The image was uploaded to imgur, that means Dragongeek claims that it is available under cc by-sa 4.0. I'm quite confident this is not the case...

Comment: Worth noting that Starlink satellites orbit much closer to the earth than most other satellites (LEO), so the window of time in which they are visible as a result of this phenomenon is relatively short.

Comment: I heard many people worry about starlink affecting to observational astronomy. Does this answer mean it affects at only specific time of night?

Comment: @MitsutoshiWatanabe Yes, low orbit satellites can generally only be seen near the hours of dusk/dawn, and not late at night. This is somewhat effected by latitude, but generally you won't see any satellites about three hours after sunset. Most people worrying about observational astronomy being impacted due to starlink are not astronomers--they've been compensating for the issues caused by satellites, aircraft, and other star-obstructing phenomenon for decades.

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to answer a slightly different question from the other answer: "why are Starlink satellites so visible, compared to other satellites?"

The answer is that they're very close to the earth; the lower edge of what might be considered a viable long-term orbit is [300 km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit), and some have recently been deployed at [280 km](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jonathanocallaghan/2019/11/18/this-is-not-coolastronomers-despair-as-spacex-starlink-train-ruins-observation-of-nearby-galaxies/#4fd645686538). They are boosting to a higher altitude, and once in their final orbit shouldn't be as visible.

Comment: There are several different altitudes planned for the fullest implementation of Starlink, but the ones launched in 2019 are targeting only about 550 km [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36471/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40064/12102). They used to talk about [1100 to 1300 km](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19055/12102) but then reconsidered, because of the $1/r^2$ advantage of being closer.

Comment: The difference in visual brightness between 300 km and 550 km is only about 1.3 magnitudes ($2.5 \log_{10}((550/300)^2)$ so I don't think that "once in their final orbit shouldn't be visible to the naked eye" is true. Also remember that *part of* the hoopla is about their [impact on ground-based astronomical observations](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34219/7982), though messing up the night sky for all of humanity is a serious consideration as well.

Comment: I was going by the article: "where they will still be visible to binoculars and telescopes".

Comment: In a recent webcast, SpaceX stated that the difference in visual brightness once the satellites reach their operational altitude comes primarily from a subsequent change in the orientation of the satellites' solar panels, not from the additional distance created by the new, higher orbit. ([Source](https://youtu.be/HwyXo6T7jC4?t=334))