# What is the time frame for the Starlink satellites to reach their final orbit after deployment from the fairing?

Tags: starlink

How long does it take for the Starlink satellites to reach their final orbit after deployment?

Comment: The current setup seems to be three sets of 20, going to different orbits.  Each takes a different amount of time.

Comment: After asking this question I heard a comment in a Spacex launch video in which they said that over a period of weeks the satellites would gradually move away from each other.  That time frame may be as close as I can get.

Comment: @rtuttlejr since there is TLE tracking data, they can be followed fairly easily, see for example: [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36507/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36471/12102) I think that "2 to 6 weeks depending..." would be about right.